# Representration of a Empty Class Array

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, null, representation

I am actually looking at getting the method, whose name is stored in the string "methodName", from the Class "CC1" using Java Reflection.

`Method actualMethod= CC1.getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);`

This is the syntax. The problem is the method takes no parameter. How do I represent that in the parameterTypes ?

where parameterTypes is the array of Class

Similarly, the below code will invoke that method.

`Object retobj = actaulMethod.invoke(actualObject, arglist);`

The arglist is array of Objects which again has to be nothing.

If anything is unclear , please ask. Thanks .

Comment: The same method worked for the invoke method too. Thanks Guys.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You are referring to an empty array of Classes, not a null class ... which is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @ EJP : you are correct. I have modified the heading appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass the second argument:

```
CC1.getMethod(methodName);
```

(This makes use of [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html))

This is equivalent to passing an empty array:

```
CC1.getMethod(methodName, new Class[] {});
```

Comment: Not passing the second argument will give compiler error. Since I have a larger code base, I wont be able to test the code by passing the empty array also .

Comment: it will _not_ result in a compile-time error, unless you are using Java 1.4

Answer (score 1):

The signature is:

```
Method getMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes)
```

So just leave the second parameter out and it should work. i.e.

```
Method actualMethod= CC1.getMethod(methodName);
```